# How to play audio file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, audio-streaming

i have a grid in my page...

grid consists of 2 columns like Songname and play(linkbutton column)

when i click play of the particular row, it should play that particular song in other web page

the song should play with the help of object tag(means it should have all options like next, prev,seek in the player)

i took a small above example to explain my problem overall the senario explained above matches in my project

Please help iam stuck up eith this problem from pat one week, i googled many times, iam not getting the exact answer

sorry for bad english

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```html
    background-color:aqua;
    background: url("farm.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

```js
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "zvukkonj()");
            ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "opiskonj()");
```

Comment: please add some explanation to this answer

Answer (score -1):

```js
function zvukkonj() {
    var audio = new Audio("konjz.mp3");
    audio.play();
}
function opiskonj() {
    alert("konj je to i to");
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation to this answer